# Account was given privileges that do not work

Tags: support, reputation, notifications, privileges

I have this on my recent achievements on Stack Overflow

> Congrats, you've gained the privilege – create wiki posts – learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – participate in meta – learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – vote up – learn more
>   Congrats, you've gained the privilege – flag posts – learn more
>   ...

but when I try to upvote a post it still says I haven't enough reputation. Don't know where this comes from since I have the reputation of 1 since losing my old account.

Comment: @Kedarnath privileges is plural, so "does" isn't correct. Also it had a typo, and last it's not unique to Stack Overflow but applies to all sites. Please pay more attention when editing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok I will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3147010/sniffleh?tab=reputation). It says *There were no net reputation change on this day*.

> [image: Reputation history]

That means some one upvoted/accepted one of your answer then un-upvoted/accepted it again. Flag post and vote up privilege requires 15 reputation so probably your answer was accepted then unaccepted. So when your answer was accepted, you gained 15 reputation so you got notifications about your new privileges. But since your answer was unaccepted again, you are not able to use those privileges since you do not have sufficient reputation again.

So this is by design.

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't see any upvote/acceptances yet though, Thank you.